# Printing all "members" of a struct

Tags: c, string, list, data-structures, struct

I have nested-structs (shown below)

in `slist* add_student()` I am adding new students to the list

`void print_student()` should print the list

```
void print_students(slist* students){
    slist *tempS = students;
    while(tempS){
        printf("%d:%s\n", tempS->info->id, tempS->info->name);
        tempS = tempS->next;
    }
}


slist* add_student(slist *students, char *name, int id){

    student* tempStudent;
    tempStudent =  (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
    tempStudent->id = id;
    tempStudent->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(tempStudent->name, name);

    slist *news;
    news=(slist *)malloc(sizeof(slist));

    news->info = tempStudent;
    news->next = students;
    return news;
}
```

Now the problem is it is only printing the last entered "student", and I can't seem to tell which function is doing it the wrong way, so the question is, is it doing it wrong because I am using newly defined part to the struct (`slist* tempS = students` in `void print_students()`) for example? or does it have to do with the `next` (in both functions)?

[an example of an I/O would be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBxaH.png)

[and another...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM1Bk.png)

The struct and main I use, if anyone wants to look at them

```
static void getstring(char *buf, int length) {
        int len;
        buf = fgets(buf, length, stdin);
        len = (int) strlen(buf);
        if (buf[len-1] == '\n')
            buf[len-1] = '\0';
    }
    int main() {
        slist* students = 0;

        char  c;
        char  buf[100];
        int   id, num;

        do {
            printf("Choose:\n"
                           "    add (s)tudent\n"
                           "    (p)rint lists\n"
                           "    (q)uit\n");

            while ((c = (char) getchar()) == '\n');
            getchar();

            switch (c) {
            case 's':
                printf("Adding new student.\n");

                printf("Student name: ");
                getstring(buf, 100);

                printf("Student ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &id);

                students = add_student(students, buf, id);

                break;
            case 'p':
                printf("Printing Information.\n");
                print_students(students);
                break;
            }

            if (c != 'q')
                printf("\n");
        } while (c != 'q');
        return 0;
    }


 // structures
    typedef struct student {
        char *name;
        int  id;
        struct clist *courses;
    } student;

    typedef struct course {
        char *title;
        int  number;
        struct slist *students;
    } course;

    typedef struct slist {
        student      *info;
        struct slist *next;
    } slist;

    typedef struct clist {
        course       *info;
        struct clist *next;
    } clist;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: When you allocate memory for the `name` field, you must allocate one byte more than the string length to account for the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: @MOehm so simply `...malloc(sizeof(student)+1)`?

Comment: Yes. `strcpy` will put the null terminator at the end of the string and requires the extra byte.

Comment: more like `malloc(strlen(name)+1)`. alternatively in this case you can also use `strdup()` instead of the `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I hope it i more "minimal" now

Comment: @MOehm  did not change the outcome

Comment: Now that it is as minimal as you can get it, work on the "complete" and the "verifiable". Please read what the link refers to. Maybe also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take the [tour]. You can even get a badge for it.

Comment: `y = malloc(strlen(x) + 1); strcpy(y, x);` is just an `strdup()`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I hope that this is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, pick up a piece of paper and a pencil and draw what your code does; that's a pro tip for finding what's wrong with your list when in trouble!

---

Your code is **fine**<sup>*</sup> now, and let me explain you why.

So, if you do so you will see that when the first student arrives, you allocate space for him/her and then populate that struct correctly. `tempStudent` points to that struct.

Then, `news` will create a new struct that is the struct that handles the list. Its `info` field is set to the newly created student and `next` points to `students`, which I guess is NULL when the first student is added.

Then you return `news` and `students` now points to it.

---

Now we are about to add the second student. We create his struct - so far so good!

We again create the struct `news` which handles the list. It will assign `info` to newly created student and `next` will point to `students`, which is what we want.

Then you return `news` and `students` now points to it.

That way of course the newly created student will be places first in the list, despite the fact we added him/her secondly.

---

As a result, you will get something like this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
Choose:
    add (s)tudent
    (p)rint lists
    (q)uit
s
Adding new student.
Student name: Leon
Student ID: 1

Choose:
    add (s)tudent
    (p)rint lists
    (q)uit
s
Adding new student.
Student name: kate
Student ID: 2

Choose:
    add (s)tudent
    (p)rint lists
    (q)uit
p
Printing Information.
2:kate
1:Leon
```

which is OK.

---

*Of course you have to write other functions as well, such as deleting your list and de-allocating the space you already allocated.

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Comment: So I need to create another function that will give a new address to the recently added (second and so on) student and then add it?

Comment: Although the printing function only prints the last entered value, so I'd assume that the error is in that function

Comment: No @AhmadKhateeb, if you run the code you posted it will print both students!